# IE9 Gradient isnt showing up

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I am having an issue with a CSS gradient in IE9. I am about ready to just do it with an image... UGGHHH moving backwards i guess.

I used this site http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to create my gradient and it says that IE6-9 support uses this...

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

But it isnt showing up in IE9

Here is my entire CSS entry

```
.orangeButton {
width: 170px;
height: 20px;
padding: 3px 20px;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
border-radius: 3px;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #ff4e00;
text-decoration: none;
background: #ffa70f; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffa70f 1%, #ff810f 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#ffa70f), color-stop(100%,#ff810f)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffa70f 1%,#ff810f 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffa70f 1%,#ff810f 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffa70f 1%,#ff810f 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffa70f 1%,#ff810f 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffa70f', endColorstr='#ff810f',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Is there another way to do this that is missing from Color Zilla. I have read places that you can use background-image does this work better for IE9 and before?

Comment: Gradient isn't recommanded since it doesn't have fully support in all browsers.
However I suggest you replace gradient with custom image (You can create gradient using Photoshop).

Comment: @Yotam He has mentioned all cross browser supports. and using photoshop images will make it look weird on responsive designs.

Comment: @vishalkin As long you use percents and image size nothing will happen.

Comment: @Yotam and that increases your development work. :)

Answer (score 2):

Support for full multi-stop gradients with IE9 (using SVG).
Add a "gradient" class to all your elements that have a gradient, and add the following override to your HTML to complete the IE9 support:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: does this work for IE8 as well or just 9? I would normally test it our but i dont have access to an IE8 machine but also just kinda curious fallback is ok for older browsers

Comment: @Travis This is for IE9 and up only (actually, I think just 9).

Comment: Not sure why but this didnt work in my instance. Not sure if anyone is familiar with NetSuite but might be the cause of this not working it is a super heavy JS platform.